# Should this specific upvoted answered question be closed as too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266386/how-to-deploy-a-meteorjs-app-to-windows-azure) :

> How does one deploy a production MeteorJS app to Windows Azure?

Seems extremely broad to me. However it has received some upvotes and two upvoted answers which go into great details to explain how to achieve what was asked.

Since this question has been answered thoroughly and the answers are upvoted, one could say it can't be considered too broad since two users have found a way to do good answers.

Should this question be closed as too broad?

Comment: If you also notice, both answers are also pretty long.  They had to be to completely answer this broad question.  Just because a question has upvotes and upvoted answers does not mean that it's not still too broad.

Comment: "Scope and topicness of Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange Q&A) is not superseded by votes, comments and/or answers on the specific posts." http://meta.superuser.com/a/9616/235569

Comment: It's off topic, no matter what.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the given answers are very long. Answers of average length on other sites in the StackExchange family are almost as long. I don't think that it's *too* broad, but it's definitely broad. On the one hand one could classify the question as a *gimme teh tutorial*-variant of *gimme teh codez* questions. On the other hand it doesn't seem to attract much link only answers and such and doesn't hurt anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this question is now closed as too broad.
This should settle the matter.